# Reduction of multivariate polynomial degree on the support of an ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Consider a multivariate polynomial function $P$ in variables $z_1,...,z_n\in\mathbb{C}$. Furthermore, consider a polynomial ideal spanned by a set of multivariate polynomials $Y_i$ with $i\in\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ again in variables $z_1,...,z_n$. Concentrate on a special case where the ideal $\langle Y_i\rangle$ can be applied to any initial polynomial function $P$ to reduce its degree to a certain maximal value:

$$P\rightarrow \bar P$$

such that $\text{degree}(P)>\text{degree}(\bar P)=D_{\max}(n)$. Furthermore, the ideal might also constrain the most general set of multivariate monomials to a certain maximal amount of monomials. I am interested to know if the above process of degree reduction of a polynomial function on the support of an ideal has been studied in the mathematical literature. In particular, I would like to find classifications of ideals for which the above is possible. Additionally, explicit efficient reduction algorithms for such cases would be of use. With the above question I am mainly looking for information on explicit applications, so that proofs are only of secondary importance to me.

Could the collective brain help me find the right information? Thanks for any suggestions!